# demonstrate custom exceptions inheritance java

Tags: java, exception, multiple-inheritance

I have been requested to demonstrate the use of inheritance on custom exceptions. This is what I have been asked:
*create a class called MyException:
-   Using inheritance, create two exception classes: Exception1 and Exception2;
-   Each class should have appropriate constructors that when used they provide a relevant message, such as, “exception 1” and “exception 2”, respectively;*

[image]

so I created MyException, which inherits from java.lang.Exception:

```
public class MyException extends Exception{

//default constructor
public MyException() {}

//constructor that accepts a message
public MyException(String message){
    super(message);
}
```

I then create Exception1 and Exception2, but they are empty

```
public class Exception1 extends MyException {

}


public class Exception2 extends MyException {

}
```

Despite it works, I think my approach is not correct.
Here is how I test it.

```
//demonstrate use of custom exceptions
try{
    if(true) {throw new Exception1();}
}catch (Exception1 e){
    System.out.println("exception1 thrown");
}

try{
    if(true) {throw new Exception2();}
}catch (Exception2 e){
    System.out.println("exception2 thrown");
}
```

How can I do this correctly? What should I put into the Exception1 and Exception2 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not print what Exception was thrown, but rather print the `Exception.getMessage()` result, otherwise there's no point in the Exception having a message in this case.

```
try{
    throw new Exception1("This is thrown intentionally");
}catch (Exception1 e){
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

You you can also add custom methods or additional messages inside of your exceptions, or ,for example, they could be extended from a more specific Exception (better practice).

There is not much more to it than this.

Example of custom exception:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

 public MyException() {

     super();

 }

 public MyException(String msg){

    super(msg);

 }

 public MyException(String msg, Exception cause){
     super(msg, cause);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

         throw new MyException();

     } catch (Exception e) {

         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense. however I do not get the result from e.getMessage() ... I set up the constructor like this: super(message = "Exception1 thrown"); ... Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: If you just call e.getMessage() nothing will happen, you need to print it, as I showed. If you're doing as I showed, you didn't build the constructor correctly. I'll provide a full example.

Comment: I am using System.out.println(e.getMessage()); and I get null value. If you can give me a full example it would be great.

Comment: SOLVED: I added as you suggested  in your first comment /"This is thrown intentionally!" and now the parameter is passed. If I do not pass any parameter I get "null".  Thanks!